# convert integer sqrt algorithm to fixed point in verilog

Tags: verilog, square-root

I've got this code which determines and integer square root of a 32 bit number.

```
output = floor(sqrt(input))
```

I want to  get a fixed point result such as this `{8 bit integer ,8 bit fractionary}` but on an 8 bit input. So `wire[7:0]` input instead of `[31:0]`.

My issue is that I don't know how to modify the algorithm to determine what I previously stated. Below you will find the code.

```
module sqrt32(clk, rdy, reset, x, .y(acc));
   input  clk;
   output rdy;
   input  reset;

   input [31:0] x;
   output [15:0] acc;


   // acc holds the accumulated result, and acc2 is the accumulated
   // square of the accumulated result.
   reg [15:0] acc;
   reg [31:0] acc2;

   // Keep track of which bit I'm working on.
   reg [4:0]  bitl;
   wire [15:0] bit = 1 << bitl;
   wire [31:0] bit2 = 1 << (bitl << 1);

   // The output is ready when the bitl counter underflows.
   wire rdy = bitl[4];

   // guess holds the potential next values for acc, and guess2 holds
   // the square of that guess. The guess2 calculation is a little bit
   // subtle. The idea is that:
   //
   //      guess2 = (acc + bit) * (acc + bit)
   //             = (acc * acc) + 2*acc*bit + bit*bit
   //             = acc2 + 2*acc*bit + bit2
   //             = acc2 + 2 * (acc<<bitl) + bit
   //
   // This works out using shifts because bit and bit2 are known to
   // have only a single bit in them.
   wire [15:0] guess  = acc | bit;
   wire [31:0] guess2 = acc2 + bit2 + ((acc << bitl) << 1);

   task clear;
      begin
     acc = 0;
     acc2 = 0;
     bitl = 15;
      end
   endtask

   initial clear;

   always @(reset or posedge clk)
      if (reset)
       clear;
      else begin
     if (guess2 <= x) begin
        acc  <= guess;
        acc2 <= guess2;
     end
     bitl <= bitl - 1;
      end

endmodule

module main;

   reg clk, reset;
   reg [31:0] value;
   wire [15:0] result;
   wire rdy;

   sqrt32 root(.clk(clk), .rdy(rdy), .reset(reset), .x(value), .y(result));

   always #5 clk = ~clk;

   always @(posedge rdy) begin
      $display("sqrt(%d) --> %d", value, result);
      $finish;
   end


   initial begin
      clk = 0;
      reset = 1;
      $monitor($time,,"%m.acc = %b", root.acc);
      #100 value = 63;
      reset = 0;
   end
endmodule /* main */
```

Improved version:

I've managed to get the algorithm to partially work, following Matt's advice.
There is still this issue:

```
for input = 70 the result should be output = 8.366
```

I get

```
 for input = 70 the result is output = 8.5
```

Is it possible to get the right fractionary part?

I am not getting  the right fractionary part and I don't know why or if it is possible: here is the improved algorithm:

```
    module sqrt32(clk, rdy, reset, x, .y(acc));
       input  clk;
       output rdy;
       input  reset;

       input [7:0] x;
       output [15:0] acc;
        reg [15:0] xholder;



       // acc holds the accumulated result, and acc2 is the accumulated
       // square of the accumulated result.
       reg [15:0] acc;
       reg [15:0] acc2;

       // Keep track of which bit I'm working on.
       reg [4:0]  bitl;
       wire [15:0] bit = 1 << bitl;
       wire [15:0] bit2 = 1 << (bitl << 1);

       // The output is ready when the bitl counter underflows.
       wire rdy = bitl[4];

       // guess holds the potential next values for acc, and guess2 holds
       // the square of that guess. The guess2 calculation is a little bit
       // subtle. The idea is that:
       //
       //      guess2 = (acc + bit) * (acc + bit)
       //             = (acc * acc) + 2*acc*bit + bit*bit
       //             = acc2 + 2*acc*bit + bit2
       //             = acc2 + 2 * (acc<<bitl) + bit
       //
       // This works out using shifts because bit and bit2 are known to
       // have only a single bit in them.
       wire [15:0] guess  = acc | bit;
       wire [15:0] guess2 = acc2 + bit2 + ((acc << bitl) << 1);

       task clear;
          begin
         acc = 0;
         acc2 = 0;
         //bitl = 15;
            bitl = 7;
             assign xholder = x << 8;
          end
       endtask

       initial clear;

       always @(reset or posedge clk)
          if (reset)
           clear;
          else begin
            $display("xholder is %b", xholder);
         if (guess2 <= xholder) begin
            acc  <= guess;
            acc2 <= guess2;
         end
         bitl <= bitl - 1;
          end

    endmodule

module sqrtest;

   reg  clk, reset;
   reg  [7:0]  value;
   wire [15:0] result;
   wire rdy;

   sqrt32 root(.clk(clk), .rdy(rdy), .reset(reset), .x(value), .y(result));

   always #5 clk = ~clk;

   always @(posedge rdy) begin
      $display("sqrt(%d) --> %d,%d", value, result[7:4], result[3:0]);
      $finish;
   end


   initial begin
      clk = 0;
      reset = 1;
      $monitor($time,"%m.acc = %b", root.acc);
      #100 value = 70;
      reset = 0;
   end
endmodule /* main */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran the simulation of the code with some values and came up with a simple solution.

*Note: The code give in the question may not compile successfully as `bit` is a Verilog reserved word. Also, `wire` instantiations with assignments on the same line (such as `wire [31:0] bit2 = 1 << (bitl << 1);`) should really be split up into 2 separate lines (`wire [15:0] bit2; assign bit2 = 1 << (bitl << 1);`).*

Anyways, your input that has 8 bits to represent the integer part and 8 bits to represent the fractional part is really the same as a 16 bit number, the only difference being that it is multiplied by 2^8. So, one possible solution would be to feed your '16' bit integer into the input of the sqrt32 module.

By doing this, you are really solving `sqrt(X * 2^8)`. The output of the function would be `sqrt(X) * 2^4`. The answer would be the 8 LSBs of the output, where `[7:4]` is the integer part and `[3:0]` is the fractional part.

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct and I will accept it with the explanation to these answers. Do you suggest  assigning the 8 bit number to a 16 bit wire, then shifting it 8 times to left.  Aside of that, I need the output to be 8 bits integer and 8 bits fractionary. In your  answer you mentioned 4 bit each, is there a reason to it?

Comment: The output of an 8 bit number is the most accurate you can get with the sqrt of a 16 bit number. The max value for your input of an 8 bit number is b11111111.11111111, which is about 255.996, roughly 256. The sqrt of 256 is 16, which is about b1111.1111... . There is no need to have more than 4 bits in the integer part. As for the fractional part,  that just appears to be the accuracy.

Comment: By the way, i would consider thinking about your input not as a 8 bit integer part and a 8 bit fractional part, but as a 16 bit number. Most digital logic is based off of integer values anyways.

If you need any help with anything, Ill be glad to assist!

Comment: Matt, my number is an 8 bit integer number, it does not have a fractionary part. The output should have an 8 bit integer part, and an 8 bit fractionary part

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I've fixed(with your help, thank you for that!)a part of my algorithm, however the fractionary part is still wrong. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't express the fact that the original code does not need to be changed. If you feed the 16 bits into the input of the module, with the upper 16 bits being 0's (to make an input of 32 bits), you get the desired answer. Let's say you wanted to find the sqrt of 70. In binary, 70 is b0100 0110 (with b0000 0000 as the fractional part). So the 16 bit number you would have is b0100 0110 0000 0000 (which in decimal is 17920, or 70 * 2^8). If you put that into the module with the zero bits(h0000 4600), you would get b0000 0000 1000 0110 (which in decimal is 134, or ~ 8.367 * 2^4).